# Cypress not matching stubbed route

Tags: testing, cypress, e2e-testing

I'm doing this in my app code:

```js
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "https://api.gizconnection.com/labels", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + authService.getToken());
xhr.send(null);
```

and in my test I have:

```js
it.only("test", () => {
  cy.server();
  cy.route("GET", "https://api.gizconnection.com/labels", [
    { text: "foo" }
  ]);
});
```

but is not matching and I'm going crazy.

In CY's log I'm seeing the request but says it doesn't match:

[image]

In Chrome's devtools I'm seeing it but the response I get is the real one from the server:

[image]

[image]

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the docs [here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/route.html#url-as-a-string), the url must match exactly when using a string which can be tricky. I recommend using the glob pattern option:

```
it.only("test", () => {
  cy.server();
  cy.route("GET", "**/labels", [
    { text: "foo" }
  ]);
});
```

Comment: My URL is exactly the same